# Connection String not remembering Password when creating a table

Tags: sql, excel, database-connection, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet that allows users to run reports.  Upon opening the spreadsheet a macro is ran that prompts users to enter their username and password in order to create a connection string.  (This info is only stored within that instance of Excel and is lost when the file is closed)

The following code allows users to run the report with the info that was created upon opening the spreadsheet.  This can be used over and over with no prompts for usernames or passwords.

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Custom_Query").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = True
     Debug.Print strsql
    .CommandText = SplitMeUp(strsql)

    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Custom_Query").Refresh
```

However, I wanted to create a table.  When I revise the code so that a table is created, the user is prompted to enter their password again even though they already did when opening the spreadsheet.  Also I have to use `ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Custom_Query").ODBCConnection.Connection` in the code below.  If I use `ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Custom_Query").ODBCConnection` from the original code, the VBA errors out.

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Custom_Query").ODBCConnection.Connection, _
        Destination:=Range("a9"), Sql:=SplitMeUp(strsql))
        .Refresh
```

How can I reference the connection string that was created when the file was opened so that users are not prompted to re-enter their password again?

Comment: It appears when I use the VBA to create a table, it is creating a new connection rather than using a previously established connection which is what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that you are running the connection twice.  First in this chunk of code

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Custom_Query").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    Debug.Print strsql
    .CommandText = SplitMeUp(strsql)

End With

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Custom_Query").Refresh
```

And you run it again by calling the method as part of

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Custom_Query").ODBCConnection.Connection, _
    Destination:=Range("a9"), Sql:=SplitMeUp(strsql))
    .Refresh
```

What you want to do is assign the connection to a global object.  Not seeing all of your code, my best guess would be to do the following:

At the top of the module declare a connection object `Public dbConnection as ADODB.Connection`.  In your startup routine you'll need to initialize it `Set dbConnection = new ADODB.Connection` and then open it

```
With dbConnection
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"  'You'll need to use the correct Provider
    ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\MyFolder\MyWorkbook.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;" 'See the link for more info on connection string
   .Open
End With
```

Here is a [Connection String link](https://www.connectionstrings.com) since I can't remember them all.

You can then run the commands referencing dbConnection and not re-running the Connection Method, i.e., `ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Custom_Query").ODBCConnection`

Personally, I create a DAL Module to handle all database interactions or a dbClass to handle data operations.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.  Also, I didn't mean I was running the code twice.  I meant I swapped the first code I shared and placed in the revised code that creates a table, so I am just running it once.